# Button 'more' in a popup box doesn’t work right with React hook useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I created a component (sort of popup box) which displays a sign of horoscope, there’s an image and description. The popup box works correctly. I added a button ‘more’ to see more description, so I used a useState for it, but it doesn’t work, when I click on it doesn't show the rest of the text.

Thanks for your help !

```
const Modal = ({

  children, visible, hide, fermer, more,

}) => {

  const popup = `popup ${visible ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`;

  return (

    <div className={popup}>

      {fermer ? null : (

        <button className="close" onClick={hide} type="button">X</button>

      )}

      {children}

      <button className="more" onClick={more} type="button">more</button>

    </div>

  );

};

export default Modal;
import './App.css';

import { useState } from 'react';

import Element from './Element';

import Modal from './Modal';

import Bd from './Bd';

function App() {

  const bd = Bd.map((element) => (

    <Element

      nom={element.nom}

      image={element.image}

      description={element.description}

      modulo={element.modulo}

    />

  ));

  const [year, setYear] = useState('');

  function handleChange(event) {

    setYear(event.target.value);

  }

  const [signe, setSigne] = useState([]);

  const [vis, setVis] = useState(false);

  const [desc, setDesc] = useState(true);

  function handleSubmit() {

    setVis(true);

    const yearModulo = Number(year) % 12;

    Bd.map((element) => (

      yearModulo === element.modulo ? setSigne(

        [<h1>{element.nom}</h1>,

          <div>{element.description.substr(0, 150)}</div>,

          desc ? <div />

            : <div>{element.description.substr(150, 600)}</div>,

          <img src={`/images/${element.image}`} alt="" />,

        ],

      ) : false

    ));

  }

  return (

    <div>

      <div>

        <input

          className="text-center font-bold"

          type="number"

          id="year"

          name="year"

          value={year}

          onChange={handleChange}

        />

        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Valider</button>

      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-wrap">{bd}</div>

      <Modal

        visible={vis}

        hide={() => setVis(false)}

        more={() => setDesc(false)}

      >

        <div>

          <div>{signe}</div>

        </div>

      </Modal>

    </div>

  );

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid storing in a local state a component (`setSigne([<h1>{element.nom}</h1>,...`). Prefer storing in the state the values that cannot be computed from other existing states, and generate the elements at rendering.

```
const [signe, setSigne] = useState(null);

function handleSubmit() {
  setVis(true);
  const yearModulo = Number(year) % 12;
  setSigne(Bd.find(element => yearModulo === element.modulo));
}

// ...

<div>
  {signe && <div>
    <h1>{signe.nom}</h1>
    <div>{signe.description.substr(0, 150)}</div>
    {desc ? <div /> : <div>{signe.description.substr(150, 600)}</div>}
    <img src={`/images/${signe.image}`} alt="" />
  </div>}
</div>
```

Also, don’t forget to add a `key` prop when generating elements from an array:

```
const bd = Bd.map(element => (
  <Element
    key={element.nom}
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I didn't know that, I'm beginner in coding :) Here is a link to my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eoeeuu?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: I edited my answer with the information I got from your code. It should fix your problem, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c4wqkh?file=src/App.js